# PyQt5 Python Scroll area can't scroll it's content

Tags: python, pyqt5

I can't make scroll area scrolling.
Added into it QLabel and grid with 100 lines.
You can see code and screenshot bellow.
Does someone know how to add grid into scrolling area?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 960, 820)
        self.setMinimumWidth(960)
        self.setMinimumHeight(820)
        self.user_interface()

    def user_interface(self):
        self.setFont(QFont('Times', 11))
        # 100 lines grid
        grid = QGridLayout()
        for i in range(0, 100):
            for j in range(0, 1):
                grid.addWidget(QLabel("Hello There"), i, j)
                grid.addWidget(QLabel("General Kenobi"), i, j + 1)
        # scroll layout with QLabel and 100 lines grid
        scroll_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        scroll_layout.addWidget(QLabel("Scroll me down baby"))
        scroll_layout.addLayout(grid)
        scroll_layout.addStretch()
        # Creation of scroll area and set scroll layout as its layout
        scroll_area = QScrollArea()
        scroll_area.setLayout(scroll_layout)
        scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(False)
        # main layout
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(QLabel("I stay on my place"))
        main_layout.addWidget(scroll_area)
        # application GUI setup
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        central_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.show()


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is screenshot:
[image]

Thanks guys!

Comment: Remove this line: `scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(False)`

Comment: @eyllanesc - I did, but still the same